# ASp.NET MVC 3.0 Error when calling generic extension html helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have an extension method like that:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static T GetEnumValue<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, int value) where T : struct, IConvertible
        {
            return EnumHelper<T>.GetEnumValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I am calling this method on the Razor View(**auto complete for that method working, it is visible on the view**), but than i am getting error:

```
@Html.GetEnumValue<MyEnumHere>(1) //Getting error here
```

error : `Cannot convert method group 'GetEnumValue' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?`

If i go like that - no errors during compile time:

```
Html.GetEnumValue<MyEnumHere>(1) //but in that case didnt get data to display.
```

Also not getting errors during compile time if go lie that

```
 @{
     Html.GetEnumValue<MyEnum>(1); //But then I am getting error during execution  
 }
```

error: `No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments`

Any suggestions?

**Update 0.1**:

Get it work like that:

```
var value = Html.GetEnumValue<MyEnum>(1);
    @value
```

still question why in that case it is doesn't work:

```
 @Html.GetEnumValue<MyEnumHere>(1)
```

**Update 0.2**

after i updated my extension method to return `IHtmlStirng` still didn't get it work:

```
@using MyTypes.Enumerators
@inherits MvcContrib.FluentHtml.ModelWebViewPage<MyModel>

@foreach (var thing in Model.Stuff)
{
    @Html.GetEnumValue<MyEnum>(thing.Id)
}
```

**error during execution** :

'The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.'

`<MyEnum>` for some reason interpreting as a html tag(getting warning: **Warning    1   The "MyEnum" element was not closed.  All elements must be either self-closing or have a matching end tag.**) and also i can't navigate to my extension method in that case, but if i remove `@` from declaration (`Html.GetEnumValue<MyEnum>(thing.Id)`) than i can navigate my method

Comment: could you post the code to your EnumHelper<T>.GetEnumValue(value); ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally HTML helpers should return strings or [IHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx) because that's what they are used for (generate short HTML snippets that you reuse in your views).

So maybe you want this:

```
public static IHtmlString GetEnumValue<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, int value) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(EnumHelper<T>.GetEnumValue(value).ToString());
}
```

and then in your view you will be able to invoke it like this (note that you might need to wrap it in parenthesis if you want to use generics as `<` and `>` are treated like special characters by the Razor parser):

```
@(Html.GetEnumValue<MyEnumHere>(1))
```

Comment: @Joper, that's very strange because it works for me. A html helper that returns IHtmlString can be safely invoked using @Html.XXX

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Yep that's strange, I've updated the question

Comment: @Joper, OK, got it. See my updated answer. You need to wrap the call in parenthesis if you use generics: `@(Html.GetEnumValue<MyEnumHere>(1))`.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov that is it, is it such kind of trick should be used for all generic helpers? why it is like that?

Comment: @Joper, it's because the Razor parser treats `<` and `>` as normal HTML tags. That's for all generic helpers.